# docker-compose.yml using 10up/phpfpm and httd:latest cannot run php files

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I'd like to start by saying that I am absolutely new to `Docker` and `docker-compose.yml` so I request your patient from the beginning.

So, I'd just composed my first `docker-compose.yml` file that looks like the following code:

```
version: '3'
services:
    mysql:
        image: mysql:latest
        volumes:
            - $PWD/data/db:/var/lib/mysql
        restart: always
        ports:
            - 3306:3306
        environment:
            MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: root
            MYSQL_DATABASE: appdb
            MYSQL_USER: root
            MYSQL_PASSWORD: root
    phpfpm:
        image: 10up/phpfpm
        depends_on:
            - mysql
            - phpmyadmin
        volumes:
            - $PWD/web:/var/www/html
        restart: always
        extra_hosts:
            - docker-local.dev:172.18.0.1
    apache:
        image: httpd:latest
        depends_on:
            - phpfpm
        ports:
            - 80:80
        restart: "always"
        volumes:
            - $PWD/web:/usr/local/apache2/htdocs
    phpmyadmin:
        image: phpmyadmin/phpmyadmin:latest
        links: 
            - mysql
        environment:
            PMA_HOST: mysql
            PMA_PORT: 3306
            PMA_USER: root
            PMA_PASSWORD: root
            MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: root
            MYSQL_USER: root
            MYSQL_PASSWORD: root
        ports:
            - 8080:80
        depends_on:
            - mysql
    mailcatcher:
        image: schickling/mailcatcher
        restart: always
        ports:
            - "1025:1025"
            - "1080:1080"
        environment:
            MAILCATCHER_PORT: 1025
```

My file system layout is like that:

```
/
    /web
        info.php
    docker-compose.yml
```

Contents in info.php are the following:

```
<?php
phpinfo();
```

The thing is that when I run the docker using the command `docker-compose up` I don't get any errors, the `MySQL`, `Apache` and `phpMyAdmin` and `mailcatcher` seems to work as it should, but when I try to visit the URL `http://localhost/info.php` I see the contents of the file and not the output of the function `phpinfo()`.

What could be wrong with it?

Have I something wrong and I don't see it?

**NOTE**: This is a dev machine, so I don't mind for the security and the credentials that are shared along with my code :).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're using an Apache2 (httpd) image; not PHP. [This is the image](https://hub.docker.com/_/httpd/) you are using.

In the documentation of that page, it states:

> This image only contains Apache httpd with the defaults from upstream. There is no PHP installed, but it should not be hard to extend. On the other hand, if you just want PHP with Apache httpd see the [PHP image](https://hub.docker.com/_/php/) and look at the -apache tags. If you want to run a simple HTML server, add a simple Dockerfile to your project where public-html/ is the directory containing all your HTML.